# scp copy all files in a directory with some exeptions

Tags: scp

I want to remote copy a directory (multiple actually but this is a simple example), but I want it to NOT copy any .dat files that it find the there.

I am currently using:

```
scp -r remotemachine:/directory .
```

But my .dat files are large and so I would rather not include them in the copy.

Thanks.

Comment: [so] duplicate: [How to filter files when using scp to copy dir recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1228466)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately scp doesn't have any options to filter files.  You're better off using rsync:

```
rsync -rP --exclude '*.dat' user@server:/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mc` with its shell link. It should honor `[!.dat]*` (or similar) filter while copying.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
scp -r [!.dat]* remotemachine:/directory
```

and let us know.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It seems to be coping things from my current local  directory.

Comment: I'll check out the duplication link.